# Any benefit of calling require as an argument vs top level require in Fastify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

```
fastify.register(require('./our-db-connector'))
```

vs

```
const requireHere = require('./our-db-connector');
fastify.register(requireHere)
```

I see fastify document is using the require as an argument for CommonJs. However, for ES6 import syntax, they use it as top level. What are the reasons for this?

Comment: Neither of those is using ES6 module syntax?!

Answer (score 1):

ES6 import (using the `import` keyword) requires that imports be statically declared at the top level (not embedded in an expression) so that's probably why they do it different.  This is so that `imports` can be analyzed statically without running the code (for a variety of reasons, including for bundling).

There is no execution difference between the two versions of code you show in your question (both using `require()` other than the fact that the second one retains a reference to the imported module so it could be used separately.